# Given $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{Ax}$, is there a simple way to express $\prod y_i^{k_i}$ as a function of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, systems-of-equations, multinomial-theorem

I have a system of linear equations given by 
$$\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{Ax}$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is a $m \times n$ matrix and $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are vectors with $n$ and $m$ entries, respectively.

I am trying to find a simple way to compute
$$\prod_{i=1}^{m} y_i^{k_i},$$
where $y_i$ is the $i-$th element of the $\mathbf{y}$ vector and $(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_m)$ are integers, as function of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ elements.

To compute $y_i^{k_i}$ we can use the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem),
$$y_i^{k_i}=\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j\right)^{k_i}=\sum _{s_{1}+s_{2}+\cdots +s_{n}=k_i}{k_i \choose s_{1},s_{2},\ldots ,s_{n}}\prod _{t=1}^{n}(a_{it}x_{t})^{s_{t}},$$
where
$${k_i \choose s_{1},s_{2},\ldots ,s_{n}}=\frac{k_i!}{s_{1}!s_{2}!\ldots s_{n}!}$$
is a multinomial coefficient. The sum is taken over all combinations of nonnegative integer indices $s_1$ through $s_n$ such that the sum is $k_i$. However, the expression is already very complicated and the product $\prod_{i=1}^{m} y_i^{k_i}$ would be painfully long to express as a function of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ elements.

Is there a simpler way to express $\prod_{i=1}^{m} y_i^{k_i}$ ?

Comment: My guess is that there will no be no better way to express it (both aesthetically or computationally). I would imagine that having a linear relationship between terms provides little in the way of relating two non-linear terms; I don't know how to formalize this claim to make some proof towards it however.